# Can adultery be forgiven by husband or wife of a sinner

Tags: sharia, punishment, forgiveness, adultery

Penalty can usually be omitted or converted in civil penalty if the victim decides to forgive or to accept compensation.

How are the regulations regarding adultery (according to any fiqh)?

Comment: Please be aware that an adulterer can hide his sin and ask Allah for forgiveness. If he told his wife too and asked her for forgiveness and she accepted it is fine. But if the authorities are involved this option is void.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The legal punishment of Zina can not be forgiven by the people. Once the case has been brought to the authorities and the required proof is established, then it is obligatory to carry out what Allah has commanded.

> لا خلاف في حد الزنا والشرب والسكر والسرقة أنه لا يحتمل العفو والصلح والإبراء بعد ما ثبت بالحجة؛ لأنه حق الله تعالى خالصا، لا حق للعبد فيه فلا يملك إسقاطه
>
> There is no difference regarding the hadd for zina, drinking and theft that they are not eligible for forgiveness, reconciliation or exoneration after proof has been established, for they are purely the rights of Allah and man has no right to drop it
>
> <sup>— [Badaa’i’ al-Sanaa’i’](https://shamela.ws/book/8183/1786)</sup>

This is also evident from the refusal of the Prophet Muhammad ﷺ  to accept [intercession](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6788) and [pardon](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:4376) regarding the hadd of theft.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to the hudūd punishment, then once it is established in court with the necessary evidence, then none has the right to omit it.

Comment: is it under hudud law?

Comment: Yes, the punishment for zinā is a hadd. In the books of fiqh, in the chapter of hudūd, the first punishment discussed is zinā.