# Forgiveness, repentance and reform are an important part of Sharia laws. But how is that applied in cases of incest and homosexuality?

Tags: sharia

Fornication (like incest) and homosexuality are punishable by death under Sharia laws.

But, as I understand it, forgiveness and repentance are an integral part of the Sharia legal system. For example, a terrorist or thief or a rapist can be repentant and beg forgiveness from their victim(s). And if the victim(s) forgive (with or without due compensation), the criminal can be pardoned completely under Sharia laws without additional punishment. Likewise, a husband too can forgive a wife for adultery.

In all these cases, there is one or more perpetrator(s) and victim(s). Thus, the guilty can turn to someone to seek forgiveness.

But what about cases of homosexuality or fornication (between consenting) adults where there are no clear victims? (I guess you can consider them to be the victims of their own circumstances). In such a case, is there no scope in Sharia for forgiveness? If not, why? If yes, who has that power and is there any defined method to exercise it?

Comment: @UmH Please the updated question - I forgot that in case of adultery the spouse is a victim, and hence have removed reference to it.

Comment: I think you have not read the answer on the linked duplicate. When adultery can **not** be forgiven, then fornication can also not be forgive, Zina covers both acts.

Comment: Just because somebody forgives a sin doesn't mean that the punishment must not be applied if the sin is of the kind that has to be punished according shari'a please show or bring your proof for this claim!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *hudud* like theft, drinking wine, zina (regardless of whether it is fornication, adultery, incest, homosexuality or rape) the legal punishment can **not** be forgiven, regardless of whether there is any human victim. Neither can the victim waive the punishment, nor can the ruler pardon it, nor can anyone else.

That is because Allah has commanded the authorities to enforce the punishment and has not given a concession for pardon in any text. Hence enforcing the Hadd is dominantly Allah's right and no human can forgive another human on behalf of Allah. Indeed for the case of fornication, the Quran says:

> #### ولا تأخذكم بهما رأفة في دين الله
>
> and do not be taken by pity for them in the religion of Allah
>
> <sup>— [Quran 24:2](https://quran.com/24/2?translations=20)</sup>

And pardoning would be a type of pity.

The only case where punishment can be avoided is that the crime remains hidden, for example the perpatrator, victims and witnesses agree to not report it. However once the case is reported to the authorities and the requisites of evidence are established there is no possibility of pardon.

> #### تعافوا الحدود فيما بينكم فما بلغني من حد فقد وجب
>
> Forgive the infliction of prescribed penalties among yourselves, for any prescribed penalty of which I hear must be carried out.
>
> <sup>— [Abu Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:4376)</sup>

> #### اجتنبوا هذه القاذورة التي نهى الله عنها، فمن ألم فليستتر بستر الله وليتب إلى الله، فإنه من يبد لنا صفحته نقم عليه كتاب الله تعالى عز وجل
>
> Avoid these immoral actions that Allah has forbidden. Whoever does any of them, let him conceal that which Allah has concealed, and let him repent to Allah, for whoever tells us what he has done, we will carry out the ruling mentioned in the Book of Allah on him.
>
> <sup>— [Mustadrak al-Hakim](https://shamela.ws/book/2266/9021)</sup>

As for repentance, then repentance may waive the the punishment in the afterlife, however it will not waive the legal punishment in this life. This is the view of the vast majority.  Their reasoning includes:

- The texts prescribe punishment without exception. For example:

  > #### الزانية والزاني فاجلدوا كل واحد منهما مائة جلدة
  >
  > The fornicatress and the fornicator, flog each of them with a hundred stripes.
  >
  > <sup>— [Quran 24:2](https://quran.com/24/2?translations=203)</sup>

  This does not differentiate between a fornicator who has repented and one who has not. Hence it is interpreted to include both. Exceptions can not be made in a commandment without proper, explicit and valid evidence. No such evidence exists.
- The Messenger of Allah ﷺ enforced punishments for fornication, adultery and theft. He did not inquire about repentance before carrying out the punishment. Nor did he waive punishments because of signs of repentance.

  > #### أن ماعز بن مالك الأسلمي، أتى رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم فقال يا رسول الله إني قد ظلمت نفسي وزنيت وإني أريد أن تطهرني ‏... ثم أمر به فرجم قال فجاءت الغامدية فقالت يا رسول الله إني قد زنيت فطهرني ... وأمر الناس فرجموها
  >
  > Ma'iz bin Malik Al-Aslami came to the Messenger of Allah ﷺ and said: "O Messenger of Allah, I have wronged myself and committed Zina, and I want you to purify me." ... then he ordered that he be stoned. Then the Ghamidi woman came and said: "O Messenger of Allah, I have committed Zina, purify me" ... then he ordered the people to stone her.
  >
  > <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1695b)</sup>

  > #### ثم أمر بها فرجمت ... فقال لقد تابت توبة لو قسمت بين سبعين من أهل المدينة لوسعتهم
  >
  > Then he ordered that she be stoned ... He said: "She has repented in such a manner that if it were divided among seventy of the people of Al-Madinah, it would be sufficient for them.
  >
  > <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1696a)</sup>

  The voluntary confession and surrender of the perpetrators and their desire to be purified indicates that they were repentant. And the Prophet ﷺ even attested to their repentance. However he still enforced the penalty and did not tell them that their legal punishment is pardoned.

Note that victims can forgive the perpetrator in *Qisas* <sup>[2:178](https://quran.com/2/178?translations=20), [5:45](https://quran.com/5/45?translations=20)</sup>. And repentance can have an effect in the hadd punishment for Riddah (apostasy) and Hiraba <sup>[5:34](https://quran.com/5/33-34?translations=20)</sup> (highway robbery) if it is done within a time limit. However you are not asking about those crimes.

Also see: [Can adultery be forgiven by husband or wife of a sinner](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/69371/)

Comment: *And pardoning would be a type of pity.* - What if they are not pardoned out of pity but rationality - that you believe they are truly repentant?